# How to trigger js event after page load in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a modal on my page that button/link can trigger it

```
   <a id="modal_trigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-modal">Button</a>
```

I can trigger modal with this html code on my pages.

My question is that how can I open a modal when I go to `www.mysite.com/?contact`

I use wordpres snippet plugin and I can catch the parameter with this snippet

```
if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
    echo("
      <script type='text/javascript'>

        console.log('this code works!');
        jQuery('#modal_trigger').click();

      </script>"); 
}
```

`console.log` function works, but `jquery` function does not work.

When I write the `jQuery('#modal_trigger').click();` on browser console. it opens my modal. But I want to open it when page load with `?contact` parameter.

How can I fix/handle this?

Comment: Only logical conclusion is IMHO, that your code executes too early - either the `#modal_trigger` element doesn't exist yet, or the whole JS for the modal functionality has not loaded yet. Wrap it into a proper `ready` handler.

Comment: I think so, but i could not find the solution. The code snippet below, seems like a wrap it with ```ready``` handler, but not works

Answer (score 1):

Try this

if (isset($_GET['contact'])) {
echo("

console.log('this code works!');
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#popup-modal').modal('show');
});
");
}

Comment: Not works. With this snippet, it also blocks to open modal on first click of existing button. Then second click, opens the modal.

Comment: Ok can you show me what are you getting in console after using this code

Comment: here it is: https://i.ibb.co/C1R0BPJ/image.png . There is no error on console